# comments in storyboard internationalization

Tags: ios, xcode, internationalization, xcode-storyboard, localizable.strings

I want to add comments in my storyboard.strings files, so that translators have some idea what they're translating.

When I use `NSLocalizedString` in code, I can use the second argument like so:

`NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"the button you click when things are OK");`

to get a comment that looks like

`/* the button you click when things are OK */
"OK" = "OK";`

That really helps people translate things. It's much harder to know the context when the string looks like:

`/* Class = "IBUIButton"; normalTitle = "Sign in"; ObjectID = "3R1-1d-v0R"; */
"3R1-1d-v0R.normalTitle" = "OK";`

What should I do? Ideally, I'd like to have some sort of comment in the storyboard that gets output to the strings file. Is there some way to do that?

Comment: if it's not possible you should consider filing an enhancement request at http://bugreport.apple.com/

Answer (score 1):

Under the identity inspector for any object inside storyboard, you can set the accessibility for **Label** and **Hint**. You can type in your comments there. After you internationalise the storyboard, the comment will be there for your translator.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This will render Accessibility (i.e. Voice Over) pretty much unusable. Visually impaired users of your app won't like misuse of the accessibility attributes.

Comment: Yes, it can only be used if the app is not targeted for Visually impaired users. Or may be the comments can be described in a smart way which is good for translator and also for Visually impaired users.

Comment: Good idea, but this doesn't really work for me. I'm using an online translation service that parses the `.strings` files and translates each block individually without reference to the adjacent ones.

Comment: Yes, The translation using XCode 6 is much easier right now compare with XCode 5 and below.